# Select field inside nested ThenInclude table using Entity Framework core query

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have a task to use select in nested include in Entity Framework core

```
class A
{
    public List<B> b { get; set }
    public string city { get; set }
}

class B
{
    public C c { get; set }
    public string country { get; set }
    public string course { get; set }
}

class C
{
    public string Name { get; set }
    public string address { get; set }
    public string postCode { get; set }
    public Customer customer { get; set }
}

 class Customer
{
    public string FullName { get; set }
    public string Fulladdress { get; set }
    public string CustomerImage { get; set }
}
```

Here `catalogdb` is the database connection string.

Table names are the same as class name

```
  var query = catalogdb.A
                         .Include(d => d.b)
                         .ThenInclude(dd => dd.c)
                          .ThenInclude(d => d.customer);
```

I try above code It return all field in customer Table but
it return all field from class Customer
I need to return the **entire** fields from classes A , B,C and
return only `FullName, CustomerImage`  from class Customer

Comment: var query = catalogdb.A
                     .Include(d => d.b)
                     .ThenInclude(dd => dd.c).select(a=>a?.b?.c?.Name)

Comment: `Include` only gets entire entities. Use a projection, without `Include`s (projection will ignore them).